# CVS commit Example from ANT build.xml

Tags: ant, cvs, commit

My build.xml has...

```
<property name="cvs.directory" value="MyProj/build" />



<target name="CVS.Commit" depends="login">
  <echo>Commiting EAR file to CVS....</echo>
  <cvs command="commit abc.ear" cvsRoot="${cvs.directory}" quiet="true" failonerror="false"/>
   </target>
```

I get below error.

```
[echo] Commiting EAR file to CVS....
  [cvs] cvs commit: CVSROOT "MyProj/build" must be an absolute pathname
  [cvs] cvs [commit aborted]: Bad CVSROOT.
```

MyProj - is inside HEAD in cvs and it has a 'build' directory already with old version abc.ear

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the CVS directory property as follows:

```
<property name="cvs.directory" location="MyProj/build" />
```

This will ensure the directory name is absolute